# Three Authors in IEEEtran conference template

Tags: ieeeconf

I would like to display three authors in a triangular layout, i.e., two centered in a row, and the third centered in the following row. Is is possible to accomplish this directly with the standard IEEEtran conference template?

With the following code:

```
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Foo Bar}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Foo Faculty of Science and Sciences\\
Bar University, Foo City, Bar\\
foobar@bar.edu}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Bar Bar}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Amazing Bar School of Bars and Schoolness\\
Foo University, Bar City, Foo\\
barbar@foo.edu}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Foo Foo}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Awesome Foo Faculty of Foodies\\
Foods and Bars Institute, FooBar District, BarFoo\\
foofoo@fnb.edu}}
\maketitle
```

I get the following result:

[image: result]

Comment: Please make your example compilable, and welcome to TEXSE.

Comment: Try breaking long lines into shorter ones, so that all three will fit side-by-side.